# Make multiple random number of copies of rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, random, copy, row

I have a dataframe in r with 100 rows of unique first and last name and address.  I also have columns for weather 1 and weather 2.  I want to make a random number of copies between 50 and 100 for each row.   How would I do that?
df$fname df$lname  df$street df$town df%state df$weather1  df$weather2

Answer (score 2):

Using `iris` and baseR:

```
#example data
iris2 <- iris[1:100, ]
#replicate rows at random
iris2[rep(1:100, times = sample(50:100, 100, replace = TRUE)), ]
```

Each row of `iris2` will be replicated between 50-100 times at random

Comment: ## Thank you this is great

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers if it helped you. I have seen multiple good answers on your posts and it is time you started accepting those ones that helped you by clicking the arrow next to an answer. Accepting an answer is not compulsory but encouraged if the answer helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the easiest way to do this, but...

What I've done here is for each for of the data set select just that row and make 1-3 (sub 50-100) copies of that row, and finally stack all the results together.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(foo = 1:3, bar = letters[1:3])


map_dfr(seq_len(nrow(df)), ~{
  df %>% 
    slice(.x) %>% 
    sample_n(size = sample(1:3, 1), replace = TRUE)
})

#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>     foo   bar
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1     a
#> 2     1     a
#> 3     1     a
#> 4     2     b
#> 5     2     b
#> 6     3     c
#> 7     3     c
```

Comment: `map_dfr()` is one of the most underappreciated functions in R

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful